Request-based Sticky Session configuration with SC LB and eureka service discovery
I tried using the example code below with Eureka service discovery:
Sample code: https://github.com/altfatterz/client-side-loadbalancing
Based on my testing, I can see that the cookie is received from the running service, but it's being handled in a round-robin fashion. Do I need to make further customizations with the discovery client?
The request should be sent to a specific instance for each client, but it’s currently being sent in a round-robin manner.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
